# Webpack not loading background image

Tags: webpack, sass, background-image, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

I am trying to load a image:

```
background: transparent url("../img/select-icon.png") no-repeat center right 8px;
```

At my style.scss and it is not working

Here is my webpack.config:

```
function _path(p) {
  return path.join(__dirname, p);
}

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        './assets/js/index'
    ], 

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    devtool: 'inline-eval-cheap-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        }),
        new HappyPack({
            id: 'jsx',
            threads: 4,
            loaders: ["babel-loader"]
        })

    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
            },

            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js/'),
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loaders: ["happypack/loader?id=jsx"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
          'inputmask' : _path('node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask'),
        }, 
    }   
}
```

I am using file-loader but the url rendered at browser does not match with the url of the image.

I think that I not using source map: https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/issues/55

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post the incorrect url in your browser?

Comment: background: transparent url(96ab4c4434475d0d23b82bcfc87be595.png) no-repeat center right 8px; - This hash points to http://localhost//app/contacts/form/add/1/96ab4c4434475d0d23b82bcfc87be595.png. But I think that this should point to http://localhost/static/img/96ab4c4434475d0d23b82bcfc87be595.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the url('...') to the file output path you need to use `resolve-url-loader` before the `css-loader`.

In your `webpack.config.js` you need to make the following changes:

```
//...
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!resolve-url-loader"
        },

        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader"
        },
        //...
    ]
}
//...
```

---

As an optional configuration, you can specify the filename template that the `file-loader` uses. So instead of having `96ab4c4434475d0d‌​23b82bcfc87be595.png` for instance, you can have `/img/select-icon.png`.

In your `webpack.config.js` the default options of the `file-loader` are being used. This means that the output filename is using the template `[id].[ext]`. Being `[id]` the chunk id and `[ext]` the extension of the file.

To specify the output filename template you need to pass the `name` parameter to the query of the loader.

Up to this point, `require('../img/select-icon.png')` should return `'/img/select-icon.png'`. The `resolve-url-loader` will use this value.

```
//...
module: {
    loaders: [
        //...
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
                name: 'img/[name].[ext]'
            }
        },
        //...
    ]
}
//...
```

Comment: This solved one part of my problem. I am using django backend and react as frontend, then my url renders: localhost/app/img/select-icon.png, but it should be localhost/static/img/select-icon.png. Can I replace app for static?

Comment: I've replace 'img/[name].[ext]' for '/static/img/[name].[ext]' and worked. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I use the Angular Class starter Pack so I don't know if you have the "helpers" class available.

within the webpack congif / common add a helper constant.

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
```

within your resolve: add

```
root: helpers.root('src'),
```

and within the loaders add:

```
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
  },
```

now change the scss loader to this

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
```

Now im not sure if your still able to use "include.path" I just add "assets" within the Url like so "url ('./assets/img/whatever.png').

Hope that helps and good luck.