# Background image with SCSS doesn't work - `webpackMissingModule` error

Tags: html, css, sass, webpack, background-image

I use SCSS with Webpack. I have a div I want to fill with background image. When I hardcode it in HTML:

```
<div class="plus-icon"
  style="background-image: url('graphics/plus-icon.png');">
</div>
```

everything is ok, but when I try to set it via SCSS like that:

```
.plus-icon {
  background-image: url('graphics/plus-icon.png');
}
```

I got such errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./graphics/plus-icon.png"
>    webpackMissingModule @

/* ... */

./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/stylesheets/main.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
./graphics/plus-icon.png in /home/karol/GitProjects/monterail-test/src/stylesheets
resolve file
/home/karol/GitProjects/monterail-test/src/stylesheets/graphics/plus-icon.png
doesn't exist

/* ... */
```

As we can see, Webpack tries to load my PNG too early and interprets given path wrongly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you seen this solution: ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834508/webpack-not-loading-background-image

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't solve my problem. I wouldn't like to link to my picture while compiling, just leave it like it is for CSS interpretation, which works fine.

Comment: And when I add copy of my icon to location `stylesheets/graphics/plus-icon.png`, I have another strange error during interpretation: `ERROR in ./src/stylesheets/graphics/plus-icon.png
Module parse failed: /home/karol/GitProjects/monterail-test/src/stylesheets/graphics/plus-icon.png Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
`

Answer (score -1):

You need to make it relative to the path of the SCSS file, not relative to your HTML file.

Comment: A small example might be helpful.